# Mouse control with openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent

I am working on a face tracker using my webcam with `OpenCV`. I have already got capture my face and move the mouse using the library `win32api`.

```
import win32api

win32api.SetCursorPos((int(baricentro_XY[0]), int(baricentro_XY[1])))
```

where `baricentro_XY` have the XY coordinates of my nose looking.

But here start my issues, all I can move is on an "imaginary" windows that have the size of my webcam (I think) on left-top of my screen.

How can I move the cursor in all the screen?

Comment: The options are simply to make the webcam the same size as your monitor, or figure out the proper ratio to scale it up so that it uses the full range of your monitor.

Comment: This question is not related to OpenCV, as OpenCV provides no such support for changing the position of your cursor, this support may or may not be provided by your OS itself.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey can you say me how can I do it? please

Comment: Figure out the ratio of the webcam width to your screen width, then multiply `baricentro_XY[0]` by that amount. Then repeat the process for height and `baricentro_XY[1]`.